Replacing the plug on an antique lamp with two wires that are identical. Does it matter which wires attaches to the hot and neutral screws?
The reading lamp was made by my grandfather in the 40’s. It needs a new plug. The two wires are copper and there are no ridges or colors to identify hot and neutral. Since the plug has the same size prongs so it can be plugged in either way does it make any difference which wire goes to hot/neutral? If it does how do I test it because it’s the plug I’m replacing.

no it does not matter

If the lamp uses light bulbs that have a socket that they screw into then it is best practice that the shell threaded part of the socket is connected to the neutral and the center contact for the tip of the light bulb connects to the hot. You could use a low cost digital volt/ohm meter to measure continuity from the socket parts to the end of the cord to identify which of the two wires goes to where.
When you go to purchase a replacement plug end get one that has the polarized blades where the neutral blade is wider than the hot side blade. Attach the wires to the plug so that the center contact of the light socket connects to the narrow blade of the plug.

New bought plugs should be polarized, so one blade larger than the other, so it matters.
A new old plug might not be polarized so it does not matter since you will switch the sides/put the plug in opposite  anyway.
You could use black and white marking on an old type plug, to make it safer or always remember to unplug the light before changing the bulbs.
